# Wagtail backend: How to use `MultipleChooserPanel` for `ParentalManyToManyField`

Tags: wagtail

I would like to use `MultipleChooserPanel`[1] for a `ParentalManyToManyField`[2]:

```py
class Article(Page):
    authors = ParentalManyToManyField(
        'profile.ProfilePage',
        blank=True,
        limit_choices_to={'is_author': True},
        related_name='articles',
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultipleChooserPanel(
            '????',  # <- relation_name, see [1]
            chooser_field_name="???",
            label="Authors",
        )
    ]
```

But to be honest, I don't know what to enter here as `relation_name` and `chooser_field_name`.

---

[1] https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/pages/panels.html#multiplechooserpanel
[2] https://docs.wagtail.org/en/v5.2/getting_started/tutorial.html#codecell33
[2] https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster/blob/main/modelcluster/fields.py#L506

---

Setup:

- Django 4.2.7
- wagtail 5.2

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom chooser for this scenario a while back that might be useful. Not quite finished off yet but it's a working model.

I posted the code up on Slack: https://wagtailcms.slack.com/archives/C81FGJR2S/p1693919153842339

It works by hiding the default `<select>` element and reading/writing to that via a popout modal.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dear @rich-enzedonline, thanks a lot, looks great! Currently we have a similar setup/implementation (Javascript-only, non-jQuery, via tom-select, currently without custom styling - yours looking way better;-)) which replaces the standard `SelectMultiple` widget. But I would really like to use an "upstream-supported" method to handle the UI part of this field. And  `SelectMultiple` or `CheckboxSelectMultiple` are not suitable.

Comment: When you say "upstream-supported", what does it need to read and write to? This could very easily be amended to just take a JSON dictionary instead of a select element. I just chose the select route as it involved the minimum messing about with the wagtailadmin form sits on top while the critical form elements remain unchanged (other than being hidden).

Comment: Sorry, the "upstream-supported" was misleading. I would really like to use `MultipleChooserPanel` - or another suitable "chooser" or widget - which comes without customization with Wagteil (batteries included;-)). My current unobtrusive implementation consists of adding a custom CSS class to these widgets and a global wagtail admin css+js. This is fine for now, until Wagtail comes up with a suitable solution like `MultipleChooserPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

`MultipleChooserPanel` is currently only supported on one-to-many relations. You would need to convert the 'authors' relation into a child model linking to ProfilePage:

```py
class ArticleAuthor(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='authors')
    profile_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'profile.ProfilePage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+'
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('profile_page'),
    ]
```

Then use: `MultipleChooserPanel('authors', label="Authors", chooser_field_name="profile_page")`

Comment: Dear @gasman, thanks for that hint, that matches the upstream documentation. Do you happen to know of any plans to implement this `MultipleChooserPanel`  for `ParentalManyToManyField` at some point? We're not in a hurry, as we have a Javascript-depended solution right now - which I would like to replace with an original wagtail solution in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To use MultipleChooserPanel with a ParentalManyToManyField, you'll need to define an intermediary model to link the Article and ProfilePage models. Here's how to do it:

```
    article = ParentalKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='authors')
    profile_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'profile.ProfilePage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articles_authored'
    )
```

Update the Article model to use the ArticleAuthor model for the authors field:

```
    authors = ParentalManyToManyField(
        'profile.ProfilePage', through=ArticleAuthor, related_name='articles'
    )
```

Update the Article model's content_panels to use MultipleChooserPanel:

```
class Article(Page):
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultipleChooserPanel(
            'authors',  # <- relation_name
            chooser_field_name="profile_page",  # <- chooser_field_name
            label="Authors",
        )
    ]
```